# Python XML: ParseError: junk after document element

Tags: python, xml

Trying to parse XML file into ElementTree:

```py
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.ElementTree(file='D:\Temp\Slikvideo\JPEG\SV_4_1_mask\index.xml')
```

I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 611, in __init__
    self.parse(file)
  File "<string>", line 38, in parse
ParseError: junk after document element: line 3, column 0
```

XML file starts like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Version Writer="E:\d\src\Modules\SceneSerialization\src\mitkSceneIO.cpp" Revision="$Revision: 17055 $" FileVersion="1" />
<node UID="OBJECT_2016080819041580480127">
    <source UID="OBJECT_2016080819041550469454" />
    <data type="LabelSetImage" file="hfbaaa_Bolus.nrrd" />
    <properties file="sicaaa" />
</node>
<node UID="OBJECT_2016080819041512769572">
    <source UID="OBJECT_2016080819041598947781" />
    <data type="LabelSetImage" file="ifbaaa_Bolus.nrrd" />
    <properties file="ticaaa" />
</node>
```

followed by many more nodes.

I do not see any junk in line 3, column 0? I assume there must be another reason for the error.

The .xml file is generated by external software [MITK](http://mitk.org/wiki/MITK) so I assume that should be ok.

Working on Win 7, 64 bit, VS2015, Anaconda

Comment: That XML isn't well-formed.  There is no root element that contains all other elements.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, you should consider either escaping the Windows path string literal ("...\\...") or use raw strings (r"...\...").

Comment: @Martin: thanks, agree. Done that in other parts of the code.

Comment: In my case, the simple solution was embedding the tree caller in a `try: ... / except: pass` block, for anyone who simply does not care about one out of 100s of files. :))

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As @Matthias Wiehl said, ElementTree expects only a single root node and is not well-formed XML, which should be fixed at its origin.
As a workaround you can add a fake root node to the document.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import re

with open("index.xml") as f:
    xml = f.read()
tree = ET.fromstring(re.sub(r"(<\?xml[^>]+\?>)", r"\1<root>", xml) + "</root>")
```

Comment: Martin, that's an elegant fix. This works when importing etree.ElementTree, if I use the cEmelentTree I get an error in cElementTree.py un(shallow)copyable object of type <type 'Element'>. I need to figure out why.

Answer (score 3):

The root node of your document (`Version`) is opened **and** closed on line 2. The parser does not expect any nodes after the root node. Solution is to remove the closing forward slash.

Comment: Assuming I need to parse this file (I cannot generate a different format), what would be a quick fix? Copy the file and create a dummy that is properly formatted and then parse that? What should I change? Should I put the closing forward slash at the end of the document?

Comment: As was pointed out correctly, the document is not well-formed. The software that generated it is broken. You should file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Try repairing the document like this. Close the `version` element at the end

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Version Writer="E:\d\src\Modules\SceneSerialization\src\mitkSceneIO.cpp" Revision="$Revision: 17055 $" FileVersion="1">
    <node UID="OBJECT_2016080819041580480127">
        <source UID="OBJECT_2016080819041550469454" />
        <data type="LabelSetImage" file="hfbaaa_Bolus.nrrd" />
        <properties file="sicaaa" />
    </node>
    <node UID="OBJECT_2016080819041512769572">
        <source UID="OBJECT_2016080819041598947781" />
        <data type="LabelSetImage" file="ifbaaa_Bolus.nrrd" />
        <properties file="ticaaa" />
    </node>
</Version>
```

Comment: This solution certainly works, but doing so is semantically wrong.