# python xml won't parse

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Trying to read bulk data from US Patent and Trade Office. Have tried several [xml files from here](https://bulkdata.uspto.gov/data/patent/grant/redbook/bibliographic/2021/), I get the same results:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re
file = 'ipgb20210105.xml'
tree = ET.parse(file)
```

yields: "ParseError: junk after document element: line 862, column 0"

Have tried [recommendation to wrap with fake root node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853644/python-xml-parseerror-junk-after-document-element), but this doesn't work either:

```
with open(file) as f:
    xml = f.read()
tree = ET.fromstring(re.sub(r"(<\?xml[^>]+\?>)", r"\1<root>", xml) + "</root>")
```

yields: "ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 2, column 2"

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: ipgb20210105.xml is not one big well-formed XML document. It consists of thousands of small XML documents (each with its own XML declaration) squashed together.

Comment: Try [Python 3: Split concatenated XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857535/python-3-split-concatenated-xml-files).